# Why does Gerrit not include the change-id into merge commits?

Tags: git, gerrit

so the git hook only puts change Id into commits. Although merge commits can be pushed to review branch even Gerrit is configured to require Change-Id in the commit messages. And when a merge commit has been pushed all the subsequent commit will depends on the merge commit - since there is no change Id. So what is the purpose not to include change Id into merge commit?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The underlying problem in Git is that `commit-msg` hooks are not called for merge commits without conflicts.

However, the `prepare-commit-msg` is called for (any) merge commits. So what I currently do to get Gerrit's `Change-Id` also added to merge commits without conflicts is to use a `prepare-commit-msg` hook like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$2" = "merge" -a -f .git/MERGE_MSG ]; then
    # Explicitly call Gerrit's commit-msg hook for merge commits.
    .git/hooks/commit-msg "$1"
fi
```

The check for `.git/MERGE_MSG` ensures that `commit-msg` will not be called if amending a merge commit, because in that case that hook is called directly by Git anyway. Note that for merge commits *with* conflicts this approach will result in `commit-msg` being called twice, once as part of this `prepare-commit-msg` hook and once by Git when it calls `commit-msg` after committing the conflicts resolution, but that does not cause any problems as Gerrit's `commit-msg` hook checks whether the `Change-Id` has already been added and does not add it again if that's the case.

If you're now asking your self why Gerrit does not simply use only a `prepare-commit-msg` hook to add the `Change-Id`, I guess that just to prevent the user from accidentally deleting the `Change-Id` from the commit message. Adding it as part of a `commit-msg` hook after the editor has closed is just safer.

Comment: That's good, though it does have one minor disadvantage: the `commit-msg` hook strips the comments (`#` lines) from the original commit message, before it opens in your editor.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what comments would be there in the commit message in case of a non-conflicting merge?

Comment: The usual "Please enter a commit message..." and "Lines starting with..." comments. As I said, a minor disadvantage - but still, slightly different to the initial file you'd normally see in your editor.