# Using Gerrit Code Review for Git Merge

Tags: git, gerrit

In Git server, I have a branch "**For_Dev**" in which the developers will be committing all changes. At some point, when we decide to merge this branch with "**master**" branch(which have stable code), I want to merge all  the changes in "**For_Dev**" branch  to "**master**" only after a code review through gerrit thus preventing unstable commits into "master". How can I implement this? In nutshell, I want to use gerrit code review only while merging the branch to master.

Comment: What do you want to review when merging `For_Dev` to `master`? Each commit separately or just the end result?

Comment: We want to check the end result before pushing it to stable code in master branch.

Comment: Okay. That type of code review won't be very useful since it'll be too much code at once for a thorough review. It'll either be a gigantic timesink for the reviewers or it'll be pointless rubberstamping to satisfy a corporate policy.

Answer (score 2):

After finishing the development on `For_Dev` (all the commits pushed to remote branch) someone then fetches the changes into `local For_dev` and merges into `local master`. It will creates a merge commit (if the hook [does not include](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19917025/1342413) changeId, then insert one manually with ammend the merge commit). This change then can be pushed to `refs/for/master`. But my opinion is that all the commits should be review separately, since it is better to examine a small change at once.

Comment: This is what I tried:
git clone ssh://user@10.251.70.200:29418/android

cd android/

scp -p -P 29418 trumobi@10.251.70.200:hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks/

git checkout For_Dev

git checkout master

git merge For_Dev --no-ff
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
But am getting  ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (no new changes) error. What to do?

Comment: Try "git merge --no-ff origin/For_Dev"

Comment: to be sure fetch all the chenges from remote again by using `git fetch`, and `git reset --hard origin/<branch>` and after merge check merge commit with `git log` on master branch