# merge commit does not have change id?

Tags: git, merge, gerrit

I am hard resetting one branch to another. After merging it with the `ours` strategy, I try to push through gerrit. I am getting an error like "missing change id". By default, the merge commit does not have a change id. I have tried to download the commit-msg hook for automatic change id. But it does not help in Windows. Any idea how to add change the id in a merge commit?

Comment: Can you add the error message? and the push command. dose the error shown when you try to push to gerrit?

Comment: check this out: [why does not Gerrit include change id into merge commits](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24692818/1342413)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Gerrit not include the change-id into merge commits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917025/why-does-gerrit-not-include-the-change-id-into-merge-commits)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Situation: you have a commit that needs to be pushed to gerrit, but the commit has no change-id and gerrit won't accept it.

Solution:

1. Download the commit-msg hook from gerrit

   ```
   $ scp -p -P 29418 TimCastelijns@server.timcastelijns.nl:hooks/commit-msg tims-project/.git/hooks/
   ```

   Do replace the port number, server address and project name with your own. Also, change the path of `tims-project/.git/hooks/` depending on your current location in the terminal. The hook has to go into `<project_dir>/.git/hooks/`.
2. Go to your repo folder and amend the merge commit

   ```
   $ cd tims-project/
   $ git commit --amend
   ```

   In the editor that pops up when you amend, the current commit and it's commit message are shown. **Do nothing here**. Simply exit & save the editor. Because of the commit-msg hook which is a post-commit hook, any commit that is made (created or amended) automatically gets assigned a change-id.
3. push to gerrit

   ```
   $ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
   ```

   Replace branch and remote with your own if needed.

Comment: Thank you, it helped. However, Step 1 is NOT required in the context of this question. The problem is not with a general commit, but MERGE COMMIT which does not include change-id. If general commits are working (which appears from the question, and it was also the case for me), step 1 is not needed! Thank you again!