# Gerrit: is require change-id and merge as necessary incompatible?

Tags: gerrit

I have a training Gerrit box running:

- change id required
- strategy = merge as required
- commit-msg hook installed and working

Regular commits work just fine, but after a merge commit made by Gerrit, pushes fail as the merge commit has no change ID

Asking around I've heard most people say they have strategy = rebase as necessary.

A similar question ([Why does Gerrit not include the change-id into merge commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19917025/1589553)) has a work around for the same issue using another hook.

My conclusion then is that merge as necessary and change-id required are incompatible but I can't find any confirmation of this